# Spark 2.0.2 Data Frame - how to add a new column consist of first two chars of an existing column?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

coming from Pandas background, I am struggling with Spark 2.0.2 (PySpark) on a simple operation.  How to add a new column to an existing Data Frame, which contains the first two character of an existing column.  Ideally what I want essentially is

```
df.withColumn("new_column", col('FirstName')[:2])
```

which obviously Spark 2.0.2 cannot understand.

Data Source

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([("Ranjeet", 4, "California", 2), ("Anthony", 5, "Hawaii", 3), ("Diana", 6, "Singapore", 4)], ["FirstName", "Sales", "State", "Cost"])
df.show()
```

Attempt #1

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
df.withColumn("new_column", col('FirstName').map(lambda x: x[0][:2]))
```

Error: Column object is not callable

Attemp #2 - creates a new data frame containing the first two chars of FirstName but how do I merge it back to df?

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
row = Row("block_x")
df.select('FirstName').rdd.map(lambda x: x[0][:2]).map(row).toDF().show()
```

Thank you for your time.

Looking for a simple and elegant solution.  May be I am missing something here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substring`  function and `withColumn`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import substring

df.withColumn("new_column", substring('FirstName', 0, 2))
```